# How to make ScrollView not scroll when I click key down or up on keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview, onkeydown

Even I customize `ScrollView` and overwrite `dispatchKeyEvent` function, it still scrolls.
I want it not scroll if I click key down/up on keyboard, but scroll when I use mouse. Is there any way?

```
public class UserDefinedScrollView extends ScrollView {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "UserDefinedScrollView";

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "dispatchKeyEvent "+event.getKeyCode());
    return false;
}

public UserDefinedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

Comment: it's illogical to do that.. why would any android user use keyboard to scroll in their device or use mouse?

Comment: It runs on our device. Not tablet or phone. It uses IR Remote Control. Just like TV remote control.

Comment: I solve it by using setFocusable(false);